# ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone + integer

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

i am adding nthmonth (2) in my postgresql function , but at the time of execution it showing error "ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone + integer"
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT pi_date  +   nthMonth || ' month ' :: INTERVAL

```
DECLARE
beginMonth  timestamp;
pi_date     timestamp := to_timestamp('14-Jan-2016 01:50 AM,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI AM);
> beginMonth := pi_date  +   nthMonth || ' month ' :: INTERVAL;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fairly obvious - the "+" is binding more tightly than the "||" (as it is telling you).

You want something like:

`pi_date + (nthMonth || ' months'::interval)`

Or, perhaps a little clearer:

`pi_date + (nthMonth * interval '1 month')`